# Formulae for sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given that for $1^3 + 2^3 + 3^3 + \cdots + n^3 = \frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}$

deduce that $(n+1)^3 + (n+2)^3 +\cdots+ (2n)^3 = \frac{n^2(3n+1)(5n+3)}{4}$

So far:

the sequence $(n+1)^3 + (n+2)^3 +\cdots+ (2n)^3$ gives $2^3 + 3^3 + 4^3 +\cdots,$ when n=1.

The brackets in the formula for the second sequence are $2n$ and $4n+2$ bigger than $(n+1)$ in the original i.e. $(3n+1)(5n+3).$

Comment: You may also use, $$\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n (n+k)^3=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n n^3+ 3\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n n^2+3\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n n+\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n k^3$$

Answer (score 8):

You can use the following relation :

$$\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}k^3=\sum_{k=1}^{\color{red}{2n}}k^3-\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^3$$
(To get the first sum on RHS, you only need to replace the $n$ in the given equation with $\color{red}{2n}$.)

Comment: Thanks for your response. To work out the sequence values I took n to be 1 for the first term, 2 for the second, and so on, at first, like when you use n to work out the nth term of a sequence.

Comment: @J132: You are welcome!

Answer (score 3):

$$s_1=1^3+2^3+3^3+..n^3=(\frac{n(n+1)}{2})^2\\s_2=1^3+2^3+3^3+..n^3+(n+1)^3+...+(2n)^3=(\frac{2n(2n+1)}{2})^2\\s_2-s_1=(n+1)^3+...+(2n)^3=\\(\frac{2n(2n+1)}{2})^2-(\frac{n(n+1)}{2})^2=\\\frac{n^2}{4}(4(2n+1)^2-(n+1)^2)=\\\frac{n^2}{4}((4n+2+n+1)(4n+2-n-1)$$

Answer (score 2):

Adding the two sums, you will find the sum for $2n$.

Indeed,

$$n^2(n+1)^2+n^2(3n+1)(5n+3)=n^2(16n^2+16n+4)=(2n)^2(2n+1)^2.$$

Comment: Yes, that is a good check.